# Make a string from array of Strings

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a piece of bash code, in which I would like to make a long string from an array of strings.

The bash code is as follows:

```
# Load all the SNPs
arrSNPsToBeExtracted=( $( cat $indexFileName ) )

arrSNPsString="\""

lenArrSNPsToBeExtracted=${#arrSNPsToBeExtracted[*]} 
si=0
while [ $si -lt $lenArrSNPsToBeExtracted ]
do
    arrSNPsString=${arrSNPsString}"|"${arrSNPsToBeExtracted[$si]}

    #echo $si": "${arrSNPsString}

    let si++
done

arrSNPsString=$arrSNPsString"\""

echo $arrSNPsString
```

=====================

As you can see, I have a list of SNPs (words):

```
word1
word2
word3
```

And I want to make it like this:

```
"word1|word2|word3"
```

This string is assigned to `arrSNPsString`, but I cannot make it happen.
What am I doing wrong?

As you can see in the code, the `arrSNPsString` should get longer, but instead, it takes at the end of the while loop only the last item.

I know it has something to do with local and global environments/variables. I want to extend a global string `arrSNPsString` in a local loop.

Does someone know How I can solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I read this  in the bash [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html):

> If  the  word  is  double-quoted,  `${name[*]}` expands  to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.

so you could replace your loop by :

```
arrSNPsString="$(IFS="|"; echo "${arrSNPsToBeExtracted[*]}" )"
echo "$arrSNPsString"
```

I tried this myself directly at the bash prompt :

```
a[1]=aaaa
a[2]="bbbb cccc"
a[3]=dddd
b="$(IFS="|"; echo "${a[*]}")"
echo "$b"
```

which prints:

```
aaaa|bbbb cccc|dddd
```

*Don't mess with IFS, always restore its old value after you have changed it. The `$(..)` syntax in this code does that for you.*

Comment: Even better, just use `IFS` for only that command like this: `IFS='|' arrSNPsString="${arrSNPsToBeExtracted[*]}"` on one line. No need to restore it

Comment: @minerz029 I tried that syntax but it didn't worked. I tried to escape the " and $, I tried to use `eval`, I tried a mix ... no success. I think that's because second argument arrSNPsString=... is also an assignement,, not a command that will use the IFS value.

Comment: What about `arrSNPsString="$(IFS='|' echo "${arrSNPsToBeExtracted[*]}")"`?

Comment: @minerz029 good idea to use `$(...)` solution is : `arrSNPsString="$(IFS='|' eval echo \"\${arrSNPsToBeExtracted[*]}\")"` or `arrSNPsString="$(IFS='|' eval echo '"${arrSNPsToBeExtracted[*]}"')"`

Comment: @minerz029 `arrSNPsString="$(IFS='|' ; echo "${arrSNPsToBeExtracted[*]}")"` thank you for pointing to separate the two commands.